# File upload pause, show modal window, continue uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I would like to pause file uploading, show file requirements and then continue.
Example: user clicks on "upload file", I show him a modal window with details about the file he is supposed to upload, he clicks ok, then I show him the pop up window to select a file from his computer.

The problem is that when he gets to a second upload input, browser opens a window to select a file, which it assigns to the first input and immediately opens another window to select a second file. So on the 4th input the user has to select 3 files he's already chosen and then finally the fourth one.

The trigger function always goes through all of my inputs.

I tried ev.stopPropagation, $(this).off('click'), return false, etc. Either I put it in a wrong place or it does not solve my problem. I even tried using `$('#add-office input[type="file"]').each() and then $(this).on('click').`

Here's my code

```js
/* Jquery */

var warning = false;
$('#add-office input[type="file"]').on('click', function(e) {
  if (warning) {
    warning = false;
    return;
  }
  e.preventDefault();

  $('#files-info-wrapper').show();
  $('#confirm').on('click', (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('#files-info-wrapper').hide();
    warning = true;

    $(this).trigger('click');

  });
});
```

```css
span{
display:block;
}

#files-info-wrapper{
display: none;
height:150px;
width:200px;
background: blue;
color: white;
position: absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
text-align:center;
}
#confirm{
color:white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- HTML -->

<div id="add-office">
<span>Logo</span>
    <input type="file" name="logo" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"></span>
<span>Cover photo</span>
    <input type="file" name="cover_photo" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"></span>
<span>To download</span>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx" multiple></span>
<span>Gallery</span>
    <input type="file" name="photos[]" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" multiple>
    </div>
    
    <div id="files-info-wrapper">
    <p>Requirements</p>
    <p>Your file must be max 2MB</p>
    <a href="#" id="confirm">Okay</a>
    </div>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Please make your snippet runnable.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, all done, notice how when you want to upload to the second input (for example), you get two pop up windows, to fill the first input and then the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always a bug source to set event handlers inside another. Every times the user clicks on an `input type="file"` an additionnal `$('#confirm').on('click', ...` handler is setted.

So the simple solution is to have it outside. But now you need to know which file input triggered `file-info-wrapper` to display. I would use a `data-*` attribute for this. See below.

```js
// Programmatically add a data attribute
$('#add-office input[type="file"]').each(function(i,el){
  $(this).attr("data-requirement", "no")
})

// The file input click handler
$('#add-office input[type="file"]').on("click", function (e) {
  if($(this).attr("data-requirement") !== "accepted"){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // Change the attribute value for "pending"
    $(this).attr("data-requirement", "pending")
    
    // Show files-info-wrapper
    $("#files-info-wrapper").show();
  }
});

// The confrim click handler
$(document).on("click", "#confirm", (ev) => {
  
  // Lookout for the "pending" input
  let pending = $('input[type="file"][data-requirement="pending"]')
  
  // Change the attribute value and trigger a click
  pending.attr("data-requirement", "accepted").trigger("click");
  
  // Hide files-info-wrapper
  $("#files-info-wrapper").hide();
});
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}

#files-info-wrapper {
  display: none;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
#confirm {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="add-office">
  <span>Logo</span>
  <input type="file" name="logo" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"></span>
  <span>Cover photo</span>
  <input type="file" name="cover_photo" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"></span>
  <span>To download</span>
  <input type="file" name="files[]" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx" multiple></span>
  <span>Gallery</span>
  <input type="file" name="photos[]" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" multiple>
</div>

<div id="files-info-wrapper">
  <p>Requirements</p>
  <p>Your file must be max 2MB</p>
  <a href="#" id="confirm">Okay</a>
</div>
```